# Calling C#-Lambda function integrated with API gateway from Postman

Tags: aws-lambda, postman

I created a **C#**  **Lambda** function and attached it to an **API Gateway**.
After deploying the API, I exported it to **POSTMAN**. 
But every time I try to hit the **API Gateway** using **POSTMAN**, I get an error:

```
> There was an error connecting to https:myAPIgatewaypath.
> 
> Why this might have happened: The server couldn't send a response:
> Ensure that the backend is working properly Self-signed SSL
> certificates are being blocked: Fix this by turning off 'SSL
> certificate verification' in Settings > General Proxy configured
> incorrectly Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings >
> Proxy Request timeout: Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?